# How can I skip a specific field from struct while inserting with gorm

Tags: go, struct, go-gorm

I was trying to make a rest API for user registration and on that api there is a field named "gender", so I'm receiving that field as Struct but on user table there is no field for "gender". Is it possible to skip that "gender" field from struct while inserting with gorm?

This is my DataModel

```
package DataModels

type User struct {
    Id          uint `json:"id"`
    Otp         int `json:"otp"`
    UserId      string `json:"user_id"`
    UserType    string `json:"user_type"`
    FullName    string `json:"full_name"`
    MobileNo    string `json:"mobile"`
    Email       string `json:"email"`
    Gender      string `json:"gender"` // I want to skip this filed while inserting to users table
    Password    string `json:"password"`
}

func (b *User) TableName() string {
    return "users"
}
```

This my Controller Function

```
func CreateUser(c *gin.Context) {
    var user Models.User
    _ = c.BindJSON(&user)
    err := Models.CreateUser(&user) // want to skip that gender filed while inserting
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNotFound)
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, user)
    }
}
```

This is my model function for inserting

```
func CreateUser(user *User) (err error) {
    if err = Config.DB.Create(user).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GORM allows you to ignore the field with tag, use `gorm:"-"` to ignore the field

```
type User struct {
    ...
    Gender   string `json:"gender" gorm:"-"` // ignore this field when write and read
}
```

Offical doc details about [Field-Level Permission](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Field-Level-Permission)

Answer (score 6):

[Eklavyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4207306/eklavya) Answer is omitting gender always, not just on Create.

If I am correct you want to Skip the Gender field within the Registration. You can use [Omit](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-Record-With-Selected-Fields) for that.

```
db.Omit("Gender").Create(&user)
```

Comment: This is great on the top level table.  It doesn't seem to work on values within a child table?  I'm trying to do an insert of one struct with has a nested struct inside.  I can't seem to omit a value from the nested struct.  Any ideas?